# Storing vs computing Permissions in Django Rest Framework Views

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, permissions, django-guardian

Suppose in an application there is a model "Service". There is also an "Orders" model which takes care of "User" purchases.

```
class Service(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Order(models.Model):
  service = models.ForeignKey(Service)
  user = models.ForeingKey(get_user_model())
```

My question is what is better while checking access of a user to a service:

A> Storing and using per object permissions(saved in another table) with the help of third party libraries like Django guardian.

B> Computing the permission on each request. Example Permit if the user has bought that service (see the code below)

```
class IsPaidCustomer(BasePermission):
   message = 'This action is allowed only for paid Customers.'

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        course = request.data.get('service')
        return bool(
            request.user.order_set.filter(service__id=service).exists()
        )
```

Does A. makes sense only in case of large computations? Or there is some other benefit of storing these permissions as well?